# Orocos-bfl not found while installing navigation stack ROS indigo + Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo and is trying to install navigation stack (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). While doing catkin_make, I get the following error in the robot_pose_ekf package:

**-- Boost version: 1.54.0 

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'robot_pose_ekf' 

-- ==> add_subdirectory(navigation/robot_pose_ekf) 

checking for module 'orocos-bfl' 

--   package 'orocos-bfl' not found 

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):

A required package was not found

Call Stack (most recent call first):

/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)

navigation/robot_pose_ekf/CMakeLists.txt:6 (pkg_check_modules)**

Then, I tried to install bfl from http://www.orocos.org/bfl which did not work as it is not up-to-date I guess. Can anyone help me out here and give some suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance. 
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201630/orocos-bfl-not-found-while-installing-navigation-stack-ros-indigo-+-ubuntu-14.04/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing the binary version of the navigation stack:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-01-24**:
Thanks..this worked but I want to install the navigation stack in my workspace so that I can work on it and modify it whereas this installs in opt/ros/indigo.. any suggestions regarding this?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2015-01-24**:
Once you've installed the binary of navigation, you'll have bfl (since ros-indigo-ocoros-bfl will have been installed as a dependency of navigation), so you should now find that your workspace builds.

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-01-26**:
Yep.. that worked.. Thanks!! :)

**Comment by [engineerdream](https://answers.ros.org/users/34077/engineerdream/) on 2018-03-09**:
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-navigation does not work. Any suggestions? Cannot also do rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

BFL is a third party library, and is best installed via the debian package that is released. In order to get all dependencies installed before starting to build your workspace, you can use rosdep. In the top-level folder of your workspace (that is, the folder with src, devel, build folders), you can run:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

This will use rosdep to determine what to install to meet the dependencies of all the source packages that are to be built in your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try

`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-bfl`

---

Originally posted by [puwanan](https://answers.ros.org/users/53573/puwanan/) with karma: 21 on 2020-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2